Resizing partition via fdisk with non-adjacent logical partitions
[Running Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS on VMware Workstation]
I am attempting to resize my "/" partition. I have already expanded the disk capacity of the VM. When I start changing things in fdisk the results of my actions aren't following the usual script:
rory@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
[sudo] password for rory: 
Disk /dev/sda: 60 GiB, 64424509440 bytes, 125829120 sectors
Disk model: VMware Virtual S
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc4b56328

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048  1050623  1048576  512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 41940991 40888322 19.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 41940991 40888320 19.5G 83 Linux
rory@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 60 GiB, 64424509440 bytes, 125829120 sectors
Disk model: VMware Virtual S
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc4b56328

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048  1050623  1048576  512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 41940991 40888322 19.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 41940991 40888320 19.5G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1,2,5, default 5): 

Partition 5 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (1 primary, 1 extended, 2 free)
   l   logical (numbered from 5)
Select (default p): 

Using default response p.
Partition number (3,4, default 3): 
First sector (1050624-125829119, default 1050624): 1052672

Sector 1052672 is already allocated.
First sector (41940992-125829119, default 41940992): 1050624
Value out of range.
First sector (41940992-125829119, default 41940992): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (41940992-125829119, default 125829119): 

Created a new partition 3 of type 'Linux' and of size 40 GiB.

Command (m for help): q

So the logical partition I want to resize is not adjacent in number to the previous one, and this is where I'm not sure the right next move is. Should I accept the original default value of 1050624 even though it is before the original sector? Delete partition 2 as well? Something else?
